# Needing $.each function to alter json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
myData = {"a1":"tom","a2":"dick","a3":"harry"};  

    <div id="a1">D1</div>
    <div id="a2">D2</div>
    <div id="a3">D3</div>
```

I use:

```
  $.each( myData, function( key, value ) {
     $( "#" + key ).text(  value );
  });
```

to load json values into the div's with corresponding id's.  But I now want to move the div content to the corresponding json values like so:

```
    myData.a1 =  $( "#a1" ).text();
```

which does result in:

```
{"a1":"D1","a2":"dick","a3":"harry"};
```

But I need a $.each function to iterate over the collection similar to my loading function.  Any ideas?  Maybe a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2d1qro70/ ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q1w1fk5t/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a1">D1</div>
<div id="a2">D2</div>
<div id="a3">D3</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
var myData = {};

$("div").each(function () {
    myData[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).html();
});

alert(JSON.stringify(myData));
```

**OUTPUT:**

You will get a JSON string as the output.

```
{"a1":"D1","a2":"D2","a3":"D3"}
```

Comment: Thank you Anupam Basak.  That was quick.

Comment: @fredsmith - do you realize that without a more specific selector than `$("div")`, you're going to be iterating every single div in the document?  That doesn't seem very practical for a real web page.

Comment: That is his issue. He will modify it according to his need.

Comment: @AnupamBasak - why is why me comment was address to the OP.  It is something the OP needs to know which your answer does not say.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `div`s and iterate over them:

```
var myData = { /* ... */ };
$("div").each(function () {
    var id  = $(this).attr("id");
    var val = $(this).text();
    myData[id] = val;
});
```

You will have to be more specific than simply `$("div")`, however.

Answer (score 1):

Put a common class name on each of the items you want to get the text out of and leave the id as the key just like you had it.  Suppose, you used a class name of "myDataCommon".  Then, you could use code like this to fetch all the values and put them into an object with the id as the key:

```
var data = {};
$(".myDataCommon").each(function() {
    data[this.id] = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Thanks jfriend00.  I found your comment to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this:

```
myData = {"a1":"tom","a2":"dick","a3":"harry"}; 

$.each( myData, function( key, value ) {
    myData[key] =  $("#"+key).text();  
});
```

Comment: Thank you nicael.  Your answer works.  It is clean, simple, and avoids div's and classes altogether.